# How to copy a piped list of files contained spaces and apostrophes?

Tags: find, cp, escape-characters

I have a list of files generated using `find` that I want to feed (pipe) to `cp`. My problem is that the files have spaces and apostrophes in them, leading `cp` to repeatedly complain that it "cannot stat". Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Check out `xargs` `--null` or `-0` argument.

Comment: I have but I don't see how it helps; I need to use printf with find.

Comment: @Emre: can you please post the full command you are trying to run?

Comment: Why do you need to use printf? Do you mean the `printf` command or the `-printf` option to find? Note that `find ... -print0` is equivalent to `find ... -printf '%p\0'`

Comment: I was attempting to replace empty files that did not get copied properly by using `find` until I discovered `rsync` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have -print0 in the find command.

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to skip `-print0` and the pipe, and instead use the `-exec cp {} path/to/dest/ +` or `-exec cp {} path/to/dest \;` commands to find. The first replaces `{}` with a whole bunch of found filenames at once; the second copies found files one-at-a-time. These commands are present on most find implementations.